# What's the mathematics behind 3D modelling?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, 3d

I'm highly interested about 3D modelling in software, and I know that it has some deep mathematics behind it too. I would like to learn what specific topics are behind it mathematically. As long as I know the primary topics behind 3D modelling are, linear algebra, topology and differential geometry (if I'm wrong please correct me). On the other hand, what specific topics in these areas are more important? Which other areas of mathematics are useful?

Lastly, I'm currently studying Topology from Munkres' books. I would like to hear what other books or resources you advice to study the advanced mathematics behind (and partially or fully related to) 3D modelling, in order to do mathematics research in these areas?

Comment: I'm afraid that, as it stands, this question is far too broad to be answered here.

Comment: I would doubt that there is much by way of differential geometry in 3D modelling software...

Comment: @T.Bongers Well, I also don't have a specific topic in my mind too. I want a general view of the area too. For example, I know that some researchers are using [Ricci flow in computer graphics](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227456/how-is-ricci-flow-related-to-computer-graphics), which is part of differential geometry. I want to hear more things like that.

Comment: @copper.hat It doesn't need to be software related. I just wanted to mention that I have interest in 3D modelling, but I'm particularly interested about anything 3D modelling related mathematically. See my above comment for an example.

Comment: I think you would need to narrow it down a bit to get a reasonable answer?

Comment: @copper.hat I agree that the question is kind of broad. But, because I don't have a great knowledge behind the math that can be used in 3D modelling and computer graphics, it is kind of hard for me to narrow it down. That's why I wanted to ask it here, so maybe people who are more knowledgeable in these areas can give specific example, like in the above case Ricci flow being used in computer graphics, or [tracking surfaces with evolving topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m3dyrP8b64).

Comment: There is deep research project going on around this that involves algebraic geometry [here](http://arcades-network.eu/)

Comment: I suggest [this](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Computer-Graphics-Undergraduate-Science/dp/1849960224) book. Actually, I think the most important topic (and difficult to undertand) is rotaion in 3D (quaternions), I suggest you look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am totally not into this topic, but once I came across the book "Topology for Computing" written by Afra Zomorodian. He uses morse theory, homotopy theory, group theory, topology and much more complex stuff in graphics and surface analysis. The good thing about his book is that mathematics in it is kept with perfect rigour. You should take a look at it.

Comment: I just checked it out, it seems like a great book. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm highly interested about 3D modelling in software, and I know that
>   it has some deep mathematics behind it too.

You give no indication of what aspect of [3D modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_modeling) or what application domain you are interested in. The field is vast.
[Lots of software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software) is offered, even [more for engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer-aided_design_editors).

> On the other hand, what specific topics in these areas are more
>   important? Which other areas of mathematics are useful?

Imagine:

- a 3D mesh used for a computer game
- a 3D mesh used for calculating the temperature along a gas turbine blade during casting
- a 3D mesh used for calculating the stress tensor of a motor block
- a 3D mesh used for solving a wave equation of some 3D domain

The constraints on these meshes range from

- geometrical aspects
- the impact on rendering time
- numerical precision
- cost to model by tools / humans etc etc

So you will find such meshes showing up in literature from mathematics, computer science, physics, mechanical engineering, electrical engineering, castings engineering, aerodynamics etc etc.

Comment: This answer is a big mesh.

Comment: I don't like the downvote system.

Comment: @copper.hat  _I'm not serious here_  Was it a "mess" with pronunciation like a "mesh" ? :)

Comment: @Evgeny: It was my Irish accent...